# How can I change time format of TimePickerDialog dynamically?

Tags: java, android

I have a button, on click on the which the time format of a TimePickerDialog should change from 12 hours to 24 hours and vice versa.

I know I have to use onPrepareDialog(), but how can I change the time format inside onPrepareDialog ?
Any help is appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally did a work around to achieve this!.
Instead of using onPrepareDialog(),

I used a variable to keep tack of whether time should be shown in 24hrs or 12hrs format.

```
    Boolean is24HoursSet;
```

which will be set to true when 24 hrs is selected by user, else false.

I added 2 constants

```
    TIME_IN_12_HOURS //and
    TIME_IN_24_HOURS
```

both for 12 hours and 24 hours format.

In touch listener, it calls showDialog().

```
    //checks the variable, and calls according showdialog.
    if(is24HoursSet)
    {
        showDialog(START_TIME_24);
    }
    else 
    {
        showDialog(START_TIME_12);
    }
```

which are handled in switch cases of onCreateDialog() by creating new object for 
TimePickerDialog, with true or false as the last parameter of constructor which opens the timpicker with corresponding time formats. :)

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you are looking for:

```
setIs24HourView(Boolean is24HourView);
```

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#setIs24HourView%28java.lang.Boolean%29)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
That method is with respect to the view, which is not accessible inside onPrepareDialog() :(

Comment: or am I missing something? 
How can I access this method?

Comment: if you are using TimePickerDialog, there is a boolean is24HourView on the constructor. You can make a variable and toggle it from true to false and vice versa to change the TimePickerDialog format. Or I would suggest you to make an AlertDialog and make a custom view on XML and use LayoutInflater and AlertDialog.Builder.setView() method to set the custom view to the AlertDialog.

Comment: I am feeling dumb! :(
Can you please help me how can I toggle true to false and vice versa to change the TimePickerDialog format using varibale?? 

I know while creating object of TimePickerDialog , we can set true or false.. but how to change it with out creating obj.. but using variable?